# Is there any way I could use linux commands in node.js windows?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, intellij-idea

I am a php developer, and I am trying to convert my php knowledge to node.js. I just started working on this beautiful back-end development project for an app in node.js. I use Intellij IDEA on windows 8.1. I still code in php for a different project and sometimes I miss my Putty when i code in node.js and I don't like Intellij IDEA's windows terminal. I have been searching if there is a way that i can use Intellij IDEA's terminal with Linux commands on windows. I get really hard time to look for windows commands each time. Is there anyone has a recommendation about it? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: [This](http://codeaweso.me/2013/12/cygwin-terminal-with-intellij-idea-13/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Linux commands on Windows you need [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). You can use Cygwin in the terminal inside Intellij IDEA. This is [how to set it up](http://codeaweso.me/2013/12/cygwin-terminal-with-intellij-idea-13/)